# How can I exit the loop in this program

Tags: python, while-loop

I have recently started python and I can't seem to exit the while loop in this text based game.I have tried changing the loop from a while to a for a loop and an If-Else loop but i cant manage to work out a way to exit it. I want it to exit the loop and print the text written below when the number the user entered matches the random number by the system

```
import random
def batting ():         
  print("You can enter a number between 1 and 10")
  bat = input()
  sys_ball = random.randint(1,10)
  print (sys_ball)
  score_board = (bat + bat)
  batting ()
  while bat != sys_ball:
    batting ()

def balling ():             
  print ("Ok! Start balling with a number between 1 and 10!")
  user_ball = input()
  sys_bat = random.randint(1,2)
  print (sys_bat)
  balling ()
  while user_ball != sys_bat:
    balling ()

def oddeve ():
  print("Welcome to finger cricket! Type 1 to start batting and 2 to start balling!")
  odd_eve = input()
  if odd_eve == ('1'):
    batting ()
    print ("You win! You scored".join(score_board))
  else:
    balling()
    print ("You win! You defeated me")
oddeve ()
```

Comment: Once you enter 'batting' or 'balling', given that those function end with calling themselves, you can never escape.  Somewhere you need a condition on which the function *returns* something, rather than just calling itself again.

Comment: Side problem, `bat != sys_ball` will always be true since they're two different types: `bat` is a string and `sys_ball` is an int.

Comment: It looks like you may have an extra call to the batting() function and balling() function just before your while loop, which would cause it to run the function over and over, never reaching the while loop. I can dive deeper and provide an answer if that doesnt clear it up for you.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. In the future please provide a [mre] so that it's easier for you and us to debug your code. I say this cause `oddeve` isn't relevant to the problem, and `balling` is practically the same thing as `batting`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! the code is working now! I will keep the question ethics in mind next time! Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully, your function calls itself recursively.

```
def batting ():  # <- 1
  print("You can enter a number between 1 and 10")
  bat = input()
  sys_ball = random.randint(1,10)
  print (sys_ball)
  score_board = (bat + bat)
  batting ()  # <- 2
  while bat != sys_ball:
    batting ()

def balling ():  # <- 1           
  print ("Ok! Start balling with a number between 1 and 10!")
  user_ball = input()
  sys_bat = random.randint(1,2)
  print (sys_bat)
  balling ()  # <- 2
  while user_ball != sys_bat:
    balling ()
```

So just stop calling the function recursively.